# list within a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on this problem, but I cannot figure out the second part. I tried using reverse list but it did not work out how I planned it.

> Given a list L (e.g. [1,2,3,4]), write a program that generates the following nested lists:
>
> 1. L1 = `[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]`,
> 2. L2 = `[[4],[3,4],[2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]`.

My code that I have so far:

```
mylist=[,1,2,3,4] 
print("Orginal list L=",mylist) 
n=len(mylist) 
l1=[] 
l2=[] 


for x in range(1,n+1,1):
    l1.append(mylist[0:x]) 
print("L1=",l1) #prints final product of l1


mylist.reverse() #this is where i get messed up
for x in range(1,n+1,1): 
    l2.append(mylist[0:x]) 
print("L2=",l2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative indexes in python:

> mylist[-1] -> 4

Given that, this will work:

```
mylist=[1,2,3,4] 
print("Orginal list L=", mylist)
n=len(mylist) 
l1=[] 
l2=[] 

for i in range(1, n+1):
    l1.append(mylist[0:i])
    l2.append(mylist[-i:])
print("L1=", l1)
print("L2=", l2)
```

Comment: You could just use list comprehension.

Comment: wouldnt it take 2 LC's? vs 1 for loop?

Comment: Yes, but the LCs are usually more easily *comprehended*. Plus they eliminate the need for `l1=[]; l2=[]` at the start.

Answer (score 1):

Man, I love list comprehension.

```
L1 = [L[:i+1] for i in xrange(len(L))]
L2 = [L[-i-1:] for i in xrange(len(L))]
```

You can think of list comprehension as an easy way to build a list. Usually, if you see yourself doing `for x in y: ... list.append(z)`, a list comprehension may be a shorter and more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
[lst[0:i] for i in range(1,5)]
[lst[-i:] for i in range(1,5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

dont reverse your list and change second loop

```
for x in range(n-1,-1,-1): 
    l2.append(mylist[x:])
```